# How can I get the full url of the current ui-router state for social sharing button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular Js and in the view part for the social sharing button ,i want to get the full url of the current ui-router state.

I am doing sth like this but not succeeded `

```js
angular.module('frontendApp').controller('detailCtrl', ['$scope','$stateParams','$location',
    function($scope,$stateParams,$location) {

       
}]);
`
```

```html
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u= $location.absUrl();" target="_blank">
          <img title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png" width="35" height="35" />
          </a>
```

Comment: Have you tried $state.current?

Comment: yup. still problem is same, but is it a right way to get the url  u=$location.absUrl();  or u=$state.current?

Comment: doesn't look that way. try adding the result of $location.absUrl() to a variable. and add the variable to the end of the url, href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={{variable}}"

Comment: could you make jsfiddle for it?